# Checkpoint file of AttnGAN fashiongen dataset

Tags: python, generative-adversarial-network, checkpoint

I want to train a GAN model with datasets of fashion. Then I follow this code here: https://github.com/menardai/FashionGenAttnGAN. I want to get the checkpoint files of them first to test model. But unfortunately, it seems that the author do not give access link to checkpoint files of Generator and Discriminator in readme. So how can I get the final model checkpoint and test with them? I cannot run and train the project in my pc due to weak GPU.